# Sum of coefficients in multinomial expansion

Tags: multinomial-theorem

If $x,y,z$ are independent of each other, then the sum of the coefficients in the expansion of $(5x+3y-8z)^{30}$ is -

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I think you can get the sum of the coefficients just by setting $x=y=z=1$, am I right?

Comment: regroup the addition into a binomial and a monomial, then apply the binomial theorem.